# How to use "context:component-scan base-package" on Dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm a beginner with Spring Web MVC. I have a problem with the Dispatcher-servlet.xml. How to use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...." />
```

on my Dispatcher-servlet.xml?

Here is my [Project Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcWRo.png)

Comment: use `component-scan base-package(com.packageName)` to create beans automatically for autowiring,Spring will look under declared package to create bean

Comment: So since my package name is Controller (you can see in the screenshot), It will be com.Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the name of the package that include all your spring annotated class. In your case you only have a controller and its package name is `Controller`, so this is the correct way to use it:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Controller" />
```

If you have more that one package that includes spring annotated class use a common path to each package and use it in component scan, for example:

Let's say you have Entities, Repositories and Controllers classes. Put them respectively in `myProject.Entities`, `myProject.Repositories` and `myProject.Controllers` packages and use component scan like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myProject" />
```